# Finding Valley Points in an Hand Image

Tags: opencv, image-processing

For extracting maximum palm region from hand images, I require four valley points. What I explore from the below source is to convert given image into binary and then find valley points using local minimum.

### Source Details:

Paper Title: Stockwell transform based palm-print recognition by
Authors: G.S.Badrinath , Phalguni Gupta

My question is how to make it general to calculate valley points using local minima.

Thanks in advance..!!

Answer (score 2):

you can use the idea given [here](http://www.mathworks.in/matlabcentral/answers/75419-how-to-locate-valley-points-in-palm-print-using-matlab). 
Another alternative idea (might be better than the given in the link) is the following.

1. Get the binarized image. Where the whole palm area is white and the rest background is black.
2. Detect valley area by the following method. Find those continuous runs of white for which all the pixel in the previous row within the run-length is black. This would give the location of top of the valleys.
3. For each valley there would be at least one such run-length.
4. From the last(first) point in the run go to right(left) to find the first white pixel. If it is in the same connected componet you have successfully obtained a valley region.
5. For such a run, from the last(first) point traverse the outer boundary of the palm clockwise(counter-clockwise) to get the base of the valley. (This would be the deepest part in the valley). You can get this by getting the minima within the valley area.

.

This concept is widely known as [water-reservoir detection](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=641705) and many sources are available.

Comment: Thank You...I will surely refer these technique..and will get back to you if any further clarification is required...